# Tips for writing effective Tag Wikis

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, tag-wiki

What are some things to keep in mind when writing tag wikis?

- Any tips or gotchas?
- Things to *not* do?
- Things to *always* do?

Answer (score 3):

Keep the **wiki excerpt** short and focused on what the tag means *on this site*. For instance, [email](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) doesn't need to describe what electronic mail is, but rather it should explain that it is for question about email on Android devices in general and the built-in default email app in particular.

Also, don't include an instruction to "see the info link below" to direct the reader to the full tag wiki. While that works on the tag info page, the wiki excerpt is displayed in multiple other places (like the mouseover window) where there is no "info" link for the reader to click.

Comment: That last paragraph obviously was addressed to me -- receipt confirmed :) I feel our tag wikis do not get the neccessary attention (admitted, many users don't even read the excerpt -- or nobody would tag a question e.g. 'development'). Would you say "See full wiki for details" would be a better hint -- or shall we ommit it completely?

Answer (score 0):

As there (currently) is no way to "categorize" related tags, it might also be a good idea to sum them up in the "most generic" tag of the group to make them easier to find.

For example, the [security](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) is such a "quite generic" tag. So its tag-wiki could contain a list of related tags such as '2-step-verification', 'malware', 'antivirus', 'lost-phone', and the like.

Having such a list in a "single place" (i.e. the "declared master-tag") makes them easier to manage as well: other places (e.g. other tag-wikis) could simply refer to that place ("for other related tags, also see...") -- and the "related-list" would only need to be maintained once.